# Problem getting sampled stream from twitter(python)

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get the sampled stream using the following code:

```
         url = "https://api.twitter.com/labs/1/tweets/stream/sample"
         bearer_token = get_bearer_token(##########, #########)
         bearer = "Bearer " + bearer_token
         headers = {"Authorization": bearer}
         print(requests.post(url, headers=headers))
```

I am using the oauth [here](https://gist.github.com/valeriocos/7d4d28f72f53fbce49f1512ba77ef5f6).

Unfortunately it is giving me a 405 response. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using POST vs GET.

Check out the API reference here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/sampled-stream/api-reference/get-tweets-stream-sample